# How to check if the logged-in Realm user logged in via "Sign in with Apple"?

Tags: swift, realm, mongodb-realm

The alternative title is "How to check the logged-in Realm user logged in via certain authentication provider?" OR "How to check a user is using a specific authentication provider/method?"

---

For an app start with an anonymous user and then linked to another authentication provider using `user.linkUser(credentials: credential)`. Since the `user` always has a value either an anonymous user or a linked user.

How can I know if the current logged-in user is already linked with another auth provider e.g. "Sign in with Apple" or "Google"? This information needs to be known in order to hide the auth provider sign-in button.

Comment: Interesting question, but: doesn't this rise privacy concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RealmSwift 10.12.0

There is an `identifiers` property under `user`. It is an array of `RLMUserIdentity`. the user identity contains a `providerType` string, https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/objc/latest/Classes/RLMUserIdentity.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMUserIdentity(py)providerType

Below is a sample output

```
print(">>> DEBUG:", user.identities.map { identity in (identity.identifier, identity.providerType)

[("611a27f9a1575af5ed15234e-lnnaeteekatdftrnsmpbpldr", "anon-user"), ("000766.23cbd125344c140b18ef0baa4deccaf32.61234", "oauth2-apple")]
```

Now you can check if the user identities contains the provider you care and hide the "sign in" button/link for that provider

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/d407cdc1c8be5f04c3decd37b88524855edfa7e8/Realm/RLMCredentials.mm

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a realm app, it checks by default for the accessToken, refresh token and other stuff that Realm does to store user data on the device after successful login. **So, the default value when you declare your current user should be retrieved from Realm app instance**. In my case, I use web development and it looks like this for React application.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';    
import LoginPage from 'containers/LoginPage';
import { RealmApp, getCustomCredentials } from './RealmApp';

function App() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(RealmApp.currentUser);

  const onAuth = async (data) => {
    const credentials = getCustomCredentials(data);
    const user = await RealmApp.logIn(credentials);
    setCurrentUser(user);
  };

  const App = () => {
    return (
      <Box className="app-root-component" sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <h1>App</>
      </Box>
    );
  };

  return currentUser ? <App /> : <LoginPage onAuth={onAuth} />;
}

export default App;
```

here I have my variable & it's setter function

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(RealmApp.currentUser);
```

I wish that helps you to get closer with apple sign in